# VBA Loop to Copy a Dynamic Range

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to create code in VBA that will cycle through a list of data, which changes weekly, and copies the data to another workbook. The number of columns will not change (A through E). There will always be five columns. However, the number of rows will change given the number of products sold. For each day of the week, the products sold is to be copied. I am still relatively new to VBA and haven't the slightest clue on how to set it up. This is the start of the code I was trying to write, but I have no clue what to do. Thanks in advance.

```
Sub ProdSold()

Dim T As Workbook
Dim Y As Workbook
Dim J As Integer
Dim V As Variant
Dim R As Range
Dim LastRow As Integer

J = InputBox("Please enter the number of products sold.")
LastRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

Set T = Workbooks.Open("Filename")
Set Y = ThisWorkbook

For X = 1 To LastRowX Step J
    V = Y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & X & ":" & "E" & J)
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to the forum. It's ok to be a noob, but this "code" of yours doesn't even begin to address the problem you're facing. As this is not a free code-writing service, please do some more research and post an update with more specific code at a later stage. Please also read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it.

1. **If you do not have any restriction on the rows** i.e You just want to copy complete Column range from one sheet to another, you can try:

I have written code on "Workbook.open". You can attach this to any other event.

```js
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim currentWorkbook As Workbook
Dim bookToCopyFrom As Workbook

'## Open both workbooks first:
Set currentWorkbook = ThisWorkbook
Set bookToCopyFrom = Workbooks.Open("C:\Desktop\Book2.xlsx")

'Now, copy what you want from CurrentWorkbook:
currentWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:E").Copy

'Now, paste to bookToCopyFrom worksheet:
bookToCopyFrom.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:E").PasteSpecial

'Close bookToCopyFrom:
bookToCopyFrom.Close

End Sub
```

2. If you want to copy only till the rows where you have some delimiter i.e **Copy all the rows until you find a delimiter ("*") in the row**.

```js
Sub copyWorkBook()


Dim i As Integer
Set currentWorkbook = ThisWorkbook
Set bookToCopyFrom = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Desktop\Book2.xlsx")


i = 1

Do Until currentWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value = ""                 'Copy until there is a blank space in the row(in this case end of entries
    
    'Copy each Column one by One
    
    bookToCopyFrom.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value = currentWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value
    bookToCopyFrom.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Value = currentWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Value
    
    bookToCopyFrom.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3).Value = currentWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3).Value
    bookToCopyFrom.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3).Value = currentWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 4).Value
    bookToCopyFrom.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 4).Value = currentWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 5).Value
    
    
    
    
    i = i + 1
        
    
Loop


End Sub
```

Kindly let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Looping through many rows and copying one at a time will slow down the macro immensely. Better to use the copy function with a specified destination as parameter instead and do all the copying at once, or, if the source rows are non-contiguous, to construct an array with the values and insert from that.

Comment: Yes this can also be another solution to go with. Thanks for adding Miqi :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can always define a dynamic named range in the workbook to copy from

e.g. press Ctrl + F3 to open the name manager window.

Add new name

Name: `DynamicRange`
RefersTo: `=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A),5)`

Then you simply do:

```
WorkbookNameToCopyFrom.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("DynamicRange").Copy destinationCellAddressInOtherWorkbook
```

Change `Sheet1` to the name of the sheet where you are copying the data from, `WorkbookNameToCopyFrom` to the workbook name you are copying from and destinationCellAddressInOtherWorkbook to the destination address e.g. `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")`

Image:

[image: Data]

When you add new data to the source the dynamic named range automatically picks up the new rows and they get copied with the named range.